# 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'SelectdRows' and no extension method

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i am trying get get specific row after click it on the datagrind. i made this code :

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string firstCellValue = dataGrid1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;    
}
```

but i get this error :

> 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRow' and no
>   extension method 'SelectdRows' accepting first argument of type
>   'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?).

i am using :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dataGrid1 is  DataGrid . ( from System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this control has a different property for that called [`SelectedCells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx) which seems you looking for.

Seems you wanna get first cell of the first selected row, this should work on your case;

```
string firstCellValue = dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0].Item.ToString();
```

And you need to add PresentationFramework.dll as well.

Comment: @Tal Glad to help. If you find an answer useful, don't forget to [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or/and [accept as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158761) so future readers _can_ benefit from it.

Comment: hi . i tried but i dont have 15 reputation yet.. :(